# how to receive whatsapp message in twilio

Tags: python, twilio, whatsapp

i am trying to build an application that can recieve and respond to an sms or whatsapp message. i have been able to setup and connect the twilio number to WhatsApp API.

i was able to successful send a WhatsApp message with this function

```
def send_with_whatsapp():
    
    client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)

    message = client.messages.create(
                                body='Hello there!',
                                from_='whatsapp:+1xxxx',
                                to='whatsapp:+1xxxx'
                            )

    print(message.sid)
```

i am able to receive and respond sms with this function

```
@app.route("/sms", methods=['POST'])
def reply():
    
    incoming_msg = request.form.get('Body').lower()
    response = MessagingResponse()
    print(incoming_msg)
```

the problem is I could not figure out how to see the recieved WhatsApp messages. when a text is sent via regular sms, the recieved message is printed at print(incoming_msg) but when WhatsApp message is sent, nothing is printed.  How can i print the recieved whatsapp messages in python?

Comment: Do you mean you sent a response but you don't find it in the logs when you access `client.messages.list`?

Comment: Your code looks good to me and it should work the same way as messages. So you are saying the webhook is being called but with a different payload?
What do you see if the you print then entire request form?

Answer (score 0):

```
incoming_message = request.POST.get('Body')
incoming_message = incoming_message.lower()
print(incoming_message)
```

See if this works for you.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).